# syntax highlighting for clojure code in pdf?

Tags: clojure

What is the best way to get syntax highlighting to work with clojure when outputting a pdf file? I have looked at some variants:

1. clj-pdf
2. generating html first then using flying saucer to generate pdf

but I'm not sure how to do syntax highlighting for either option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pygmentize and output to rtf (and then print to a file) or to latex and then pdflatex creates the pdf.

It's a python package you can easy_install or pip if you need.

Juan Manuel

Comment: And with ``pygmentize`` installed, one might as well use [minted](http://code.google.com/p/minted/) to write the code directly in Latex.